# BandStructure.java missing upgrading to jdk 11 from jdk 8

Tags: java, java-11

```
openjdk-8u45-b14\jdk\src\share\classes\com\sun\java\util\jar\pack\BandStructure.java
```

BandStructure.java is removed in jdk11, I am upgrading to jdk 11 from jdk 8 and the above file is not present in source code of jdk 11.
Please suggest any alternative

Comment: Could you please provide more context around what you mean? Question is not clear, pls provide more details, share code snippet etc.

Comment: have you looked up it's documentation? classes are never removed without providing an alternative, or explaining what library to import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BandStructure` does still exist in Java 11, but the Java compiler + module system now makes it harder for application code to depend on JVM internal classes.

The `BandStructure` class still exists in the OpenJDK codebase up to Java 13 but it is gone in Java 14.  Thus class is a component of the old `pack200` and `unpack200` utilities that were deprecated in Java 11 and removed in Java 14.

Is there a replacement for `BandStructure`?

Well, in the general sense ... no there isn't.  The `pack200` and `unpack200` commands have been removed from the codebase.

There might be a replacement for your particular use of `BandStructure` ... but we cannot advise you about that unless you provide more details.

---

If you desperately wanted to keep using `BandStructure` in Java 11, you *could* consider using `--add-exports` etcetera as described in [JEP 261](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261).  However, this is only putting off the problem until later.  By Java 14, the class is **completely gone**.

---

Note that it was always a bad idea to write applications that depended on internal classes from `com.sun.*` packages.  The documentation has always warned that such classes could be changed or removed.  In this case, it has happened.

Answer (score 0):

## *Pack200* gone

The [*Pack200*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pack200) feature was removed in Java 14. Thus your missing class.

See [*JEP 367: Remove the Pack200 Tools and API*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/367).

---

To avoid these surprises, I suggest:

- Reading the release notes for every version of Java
- Compiling and testing with each non-[LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Java